# Xcode 11.0 'Rename Failed' when trying to rename file

Tags: xcode

I am trying to rename a file in the Xcode file browser, and I get message saying

> Rename Failed
>
> Could not rename "main.m" to "Main.c".

No matter what I attempt to rename any file to the error persists

Why is Xcode unable to simply rename a file? Is there a fix?

Comment: Xcode 11? Really?

Comment: @matt Is there an issue with that?

Comment: Well that depends on your purpose in life. :) It's very old so you can hardly expect us  (or Apple) to be interested in bugs it may have. (No one here is likely even to be able to reproduce them; I can't run Xcode 11 at all.) And it has no practical purpose, as it cannot be used to submit apps to the App Store. So why bother worrying about how it behaves?

Comment: Can you rename the file yourself in the Finder?

Comment: @Caleb I do not see why not but would that work properly?

Comment: @matt Xcode 11 is from 2019 so not too old or is 2 years in technology years a lot?

Comment: @user16217248 Xcode does generally notice file system events like renaming files; I've renamed files in the Finder and had the change automatically appear in my Xcode project. So try it and see. Worst case, you just remove the file from your project, rename it, and add it back. And yes, 2 years and 2 major-version updates makes a big difference. Unless you're stuck working on some very old hardware, there's little reason to use Xcode 11 instead of 13.

Comment: As I've said, in the lives of most of us, Xcode 11 is totally useless for practical purposes.